# Can the hover interval be changed?

Tags: c#, winforms, hover

I have code that allows a user to hover over a control, and it will respond. However, I'd like the hovering to fire a little quicker. Is there a way to speed up the hover reaction?

Comment: doubt it, but slowing it down shouldn't be hard at all.

Comment: How do you determine hovering over? what event? Have you tried MouseEnter or some of the Preview... events?

Comment: @Denis - I'm using the MouseHover event.

Answer (score 6):

There is an intentional time delay of `SystemInformation.MouseHoverTime` milliseconds before the `MouseHover` event is generated, as a simple alternative you can use the `MouseEnter` event instead, which will trigger immediately.

Comment: That setting is used for ToolTip. But the `MouseHover` event is following the value of `dwHoverTime` field of [`NativeMethods.TRACKMOUSEEVENT`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/NativeMethods.cs,63eece627fb00887) which is set to 100 milliseconds.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. The hover in Windows Forms is not following the global system setting and it has been set in [`NativeMethods.TRACKMOUSEEVENT`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/NativeMethods.cs,63eece627fb00887) to 100 milliseconds in the `dwHoverTime` field.

Then in `WndProc` method of the native window of the control, `WM_MOUSEMOVE` has been trapped to call `TrackMouseEvent` which in turn cause a `WM_MOUSEHOVER`. You can see the source code [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,14496).

So you can handle `WM_MOUSEMOVE` and call [`TrackMouseEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-trackmouseevent) by setting desired timeout for mouse hover as `dwHoverTime` field of the [`TRACKMOUSEEVENT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/ns-winuser-tagtrackmouseevent). Also handle `WM_MOUSEHOVER` and raise a custom event like `MyMouseHover`.

Then you can easily handle this custom `MyMouseHover` event.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class SampleControl : Control
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int TrackMouseEvent(ref TRACKMOUSEEVENT lpEventTrack);
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct TRACKMOUSEEVENT
    {
        public uint cbSize;
        public uint dwFlags;
        public IntPtr hwndTrack;
        public uint dwHoverTime;
        public static readonly TRACKMOUSEEVENT Empty;
    }
    private TRACKMOUSEEVENT track = TRACKMOUSEEVENT.Empty;
    const int WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200;
    const int WM_MOUSEHOVER = 0x02A1;
    const int TME_HOVER = 0x1;
    const int TME_LEAVE = 0x2;
    public event EventHandler MyMouseHover;
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_MOUSEMOVE)
        {
            track.hwndTrack = this.Handle;
            track.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(track);
            track.dwFlags = TME_HOVER | TME_LEAVE;
            track.dwHoverTime = 500;
            TrackMouseEvent(ref track);
        }
        if(m.Msg == WM_MOUSEHOVER)
        {
            MyMouseHover?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

**Notes**

- The system-wide `SystemInformation.MouseHoverTime` setting is used for `ToolTip`. But the `MouseHover` event is following the value of `dwHoverTime` field of [`NativeMethods.TRACKMOUSEEVENT`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/NativeMethods.cs,63eece627fb00887) which is set to 100 milliseconds.
- You can find a similar implementation in my post for handling hover event on title bar of a form: [Handle Mouse Hover on Titlebar of Form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683532/3110834).
- As another option I also tried setting value of `dwHoverTime` field of the private `trackMouseEvent` field of the control and this solution also seems to be working.
- You can find VB version of the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54582106/3110834).

Answer (score 2):

If you use the `ToolTip` component for this purpose, you can set its `InitialDelay` property to a value smaller than the default 500 (half a second).

By the way, the `AutoPopDelay` and `ReshowDelay` properties are also useful, determining the display time and the delay upon the mouse re-entering the control's client area, respectively.

Comment: I'm not responding with textual feedback, I'm "highlighting" the TextBox by changing its BackColor property.

Comment: @ClayShannon: So you are trying to adjust the mouse hover time itself, right? This is a per-user Windows setting that you can change with TweakUI (on XP) or by directly editing the registry (HKCU\Control Panel\Mouse\MouseHoverTime).

Comment: OK, probably not feasible then. The users will have to be a little more patient.

Comment: @ClayShannon: Oh, not all is lost, you can always write your own component around it, say, using the MouseEnter/MouseMove/MouseLeave events (or their virtual method counterparts) and a timer.