# Handle Mouse Hover on Titlebar of Form - Show Title of a Minimized MDI Child in ToolTip

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, mdi

I'm looking for a message like `WM_NCMOUSEMOVE` that represents the mouse is hovering on title bar of a form.

Currently I've put this code in child forms, but the problem is that they are many child forms and also it doesn't handle a mouse hover on title bar:

```vb
Private Const WM_NCMOUSEMOVE = &HA0
Dim stado_min As Boolean

Protected Overrides Sub DefWndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    If stado_min AndAlso CLng(m.Msg) = WM_NCMOUSEMOVE Then 
        form_principal.ToolTipTitulo.SetToolTip(Me, Label1.Text)
    End If
    MyBase.DefWndProc(m)
End Sub

Private Sub schanged() Handles MyBase.SizeChanged
    stado_min = (Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized)
End Sub
```

In fact I'm looking for a solution to show title of an MDI child in tooltip when the mouse hovers over the minimized MDI child. How can I do that?

Comment: why are you using DefWndProc instead of Form.MouseHover ?

Comment: The OP is trying to handle mouse hover on non-client area. And surely the question doesn't deserve a downvote even if they are using the wrong way.

Comment: There aren't downvotes in this question.

Comment: @Reza - you are a very smart guy.  Please use your talents to explain how you could hover the title bar on a minimized window or why an MDI window requires a tooltip when the title bar already displays its name.  We'll need that kind of help to make sense of the question.

Comment: in c# exists any tool similar to "AutoIt3 Window Spy" but get and dysplay current m System.Windows.Forms.Message?

Comment: I only try to clarify the question, because I think neither "DefWndProc" or "OnMouseOver" will not detect mouse events on form's caption. Time ago, there was a tool that identify HWND id, by simply hover the mouse over windows/controls. Maybe I'm wrong, but I think MdiParentForm should capture the mouse to get this messages.

Comment: Just in case you want to try, there is an article in CodeProject that maybe can help you in this task. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C

Comment: @HansPassant The screenshot in the answer shows a sample usage of `WM_NCMOUSEHOVER`.

Comment: MDI application are considered obsolete from long ago... Why not using a tabbed MDI interface instead and never have minimized child.

Comment: @HansPassant After I created the example I saw the title-bar of minimized MDI child form doesn't show the title, so showing a tooltip containing the title seems reasonable, may be not the best solution. I also edited the question to be more clear for future readers. Let me know if you have any idea about it.

Comment: @HansPassant By the way, I removed my comment based on [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40680482/handle-mouse-hover-on-titlebar-of-form-show-title-of-a-minimized-mdi-child-in#comment68594778_40680482). Hope to see just technical feedback and debates which makes the site better and be useful for users. Regards :)

Comment: @HansPassant If a minimized window is too small to show the title it could be useful to show it on hover.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To handle a mouse hover over non-client area, you can trap [`WM_NCMOUSEHOVER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-ncmousehover?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) in [`WndProc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.Form.wndproc?view=windowsdesktop-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235).
As mentioned in documentations hover tracking stops when this message is generated. The application must call [`TrackMouseEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-trackmouseevent?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) again if it requires further tracking of mouse hover behavior.

**NonClientMouseHover Event Implementation**

In below code, a `NonClientMouseHover` has been raised by trapping `WM_NCMOUSEHOVER`. You can handle `NonClientMouseHover` event like any other events of the form:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

```
public class SampleForm : Form
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int TrackMouseEvent(ref TRACK_MOUSE_EVENT lpEventTrack);
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct TRACK_MOUSE_EVENT {
        public uint cbSize;
        public uint dwFlags;
        public IntPtr hwndTrack;
        public uint dwHoverTime;
        public static readonly TRACK_MOUSE_EVENT Empty;
    }
    private TRACK_MOUSE_EVENT track = TRACK_MOUSE_EVENT.Empty;
    const int WM_NCMOUSEMOVE = 0xA0;
    const int WM_NCMOUSEHOVER = 0x2A0;
    const int TME_HOVER = 0x1;
    const int TME_NONCLIENT = 0x10;
    public event EventHandler NonClientMouseHover;
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        if (m.Msg == WM_NCMOUSEMOVE) {
            track.hwndTrack = this.Handle;
            track.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(track);
            track.dwFlags = TME_HOVER | TME_NONCLIENT;
            track.dwHoverTime = 500;
            TrackMouseEvent(ref track);
        }
        if (m.Msg == WM_NCMOUSEHOVER) {
            var handler = NonClientMouseHover;
            if (handler != null)
                NonClientMouseHover(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

**Example**

Based on your question it seems you are interested to the event for a minimized mdi child window. The event also raises for a minimized mdi child form, so if for any reason you want to do something when the mouse hover title bar of a minimized mdi child, you can check `if(((Form)sender).WindowState== FormWindowState.Minimized)`. Also `((Form)sender).Text` is text of the form which raised the event.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    ToolTip toolTip1 = new ToolTip();
    public Form1()
    {
        //InitializeComponent();
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.IsMdiContainer = true;
        var f1 = new SampleForm() { Text = "Some Form", MdiParent = this };
        f1.NonClientMouseHover += child_NonClientMouseHover;
        f1.Show();
        var f2 = new SampleForm() { Text = "Some Other Form", MdiParent = this };
        f2.NonClientMouseHover += child_NonClientMouseHover;
        f2.Show();
    }
    void child_NonClientMouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var f = (Form)sender;
        var p = f.PointToClient(f.Parent.PointToScreen(f.Location));
        p.Offset(0, -24);
        toolTip1.Show(f.Text, f, p, 2000);
    }
    protected override void OnFormClosed(FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        toolTip1.Dispose();
        base.OnFormClosed(e);
    }
}
```

[image]

**Note:** Thanks to [Bob](https://www.experts-exchange.com/members/TheLearnedOne.html) for his post [here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/22930435/MDI-Child-Non-Client-Area-Mouse-Hover.html). The initial code for handling `WM_NCMOUSEHOVER` has taken from there and made working with some changes and removing some parts.

Comment: Excellent to that I was referring, is it possible add implement NonClientMouseMove event?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Just declare `public event EventHandler NonClientMouseMove;` and check when `m.Msg == WM_NCMOUSEMOVE` then raise the event like I did for `NonClientMouseHover`. Also if you take a look at [Bob's post](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/22930435/MDI-Child-Non-Client-Area-Mouse-Hover.html) you will see an implementation of `NonClientMouseMove` which its event args contains mouse position as well.