# Setting form's width according to text in title bar

Tags: c#, winforms, autosize

When (or after) I call my `Form.Show()` method, I would like to set the form's width (or minimum width) according to the string in the title bar (`Form.Text`), since this text is changing according to a user's choice. The form width should end up being the perfect amount so that the title bar text doesn't cut off and end with "...".
Currently, I'm simply setting the `MinimumSize` property to a value that accommodates for all choices, but an automatic sizing would look slightly neater. My problem here is that the title bar text doesn't have any properties to get its actual width. `AutoSize` also only changes the size according to the controls in the form.

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: You may find this post useful: [Add a ToolTip to the Form titlebar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65863602/3110834)

Comment: Maybe you could take a look at measuring the text length. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.measuretext

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the width of the system menu, width of the title text and width of control box buttons, then calculate the preferred width and check if the current width is less that the preferred with, then change the widths of the for to preferred width.

[image: auto-size based on title text width]

To get the information about titlebar elements, you can send a [WM_GETTITLEBARINFOEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-gettitlebarinfoex?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) message to window and get an instance of [TITLEBARINFOEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-titlebarinfoex?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) structure which contains information about titlebar.

You can also use [SystemInformation.CaptionButtonSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.captionbuttonsize?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) to get control button sizes and [SystemInformation.SmallIconSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.smalliconsize?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) to get system menu icon size and add a bit of extra padding space.

**Example**

You can override OnShown method of the form like this:

```
protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnShown(e);

    var info = NativeMethods.GetTitleBarInfo(this.Handle);
    var systemMenuWidth = info.rcTitleBar.Left - this.Left;
    var controlBoxWidth =
        info.rgrect[(int)NativeMethods.TitleBarRectangles.CloseButton].Right -
        info.rgrect[(int)NativeMethods.TitleBarRectangles.MinimizeButton].Left;
    var titleWidth = TextRenderer.MeasureText(this.Text, SystemFonts.CaptionFont).Width;

    //var preferred = titleWidth + systemMenuWidth + controlBoxWidth + 16;
    //if (this.Width < preferred)
    //   this.Width = preferred;

    var preferred = titleWidth + systemMenuWidth + controlBoxWidth;
    if (this.Width < preferred)
        this.ClientSize = new Size(preferred, this.ClientSize.Height);
}
```

And here is NativeMethods:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public static class NativeMethods
{
    public const int WM_GETTITLEBARINFOEX = 0x033F;
    public static TITLEBARINFOEX GetTitleBarInfo(IntPtr hwnd)
    {
        var info = new TITLEBARINFOEX()
        { cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(TITLEBARINFOEX)) };
        SendMessage(hwnd, WM_GETTITLEBARINFOEX, IntPtr.Zero, ref info);
        return info;
    }
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(
        IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, ref TITLEBARINFOEX lParam);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct TITLEBARINFOEX
    {
        public const int CCHILDREN_TITLEBAR = 5;
        public uint cbSize;
        public RECT rcTitleBar;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = CCHILDREN_TITLEBAR + 1)]
        public uint[] rgstate;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = CCHILDREN_TITLEBAR + 1)]
        public RECT[] rgrect;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RECT
    {
        public int Left, Top, Right, Bottom;
        public Rectangle ToRectangle() => Rectangle.FromLTRB(Left, Top, Right, Bottom);
    }
    public enum TitleBarRectangles
    {
        TitleBar = 0,
        Reserved = 1,
        MinimizeButton = 2,
        MaximizeButton = 3,
        HelpButton = 4,
        CloseButton = 5
    }
}
```

So having such form in designer:

[image: form in design mode]

But at runtime:

[image: auto-size based on title text width]

#### Alternative solution - Set tooltip for titlebar

As an alternative solution you can [add a ToolTip to the Form titlebar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65863602/3110834):

[image: Tooltip for titlebar]

Comment: A suggestion. This measure is of course correct: `var preferred = titleWidth + systemMenuWidth + controlBoxWidth`. That `+ 16` is *smelly*. You could use `AdjustWindowRectEx()` to adapt this measure to the current Stye and ExStyle of the Window, passing `preferred` as the new Width of the ClientArea that generates the overall size of the Windows, so the function will do all the adjustments without hard-coding a *spacer* (I know, it adds more function calls, to also get the current Styles :).

Comment: @Jimi I agree, I just have added 16 as a little bit padding to be on safe side. I tried by setting ClientSize and it worked, so I updated the post.